# Using CONCAT with MySQL Triggers (Error at ,)

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, concatenation

I am trying to create a trigger to write logs when rows in x table have been edited.

This is the current query..

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users_backlog
    (user_id, description, datetime) VALUES (user_id,
    CONCAT('modified from ', OLD.value, ' to ', NEW.value), CURTIMESTAMP());
END
```

The console returns the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:
Schema for relevant tables
Users:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hourly` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_paid` date DEFAULT NULL
;
```

Users_backlog:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_backlog` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: 1st, Where is `OLD.value` and `NEW.value` came from? I can see that you haven't declare those. 2nd is the `CURTIMESTAMP()` will return a `TIMESTAMP` not a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @ChristianMark Ah I havent declared this, the 'value' column are both decimal(10, 2)

Comment: @imran please show table schema for `users` table

Comment: Also there is no function called CURTIMESTAMP() in MySQL...

Comment: So what is the actual table name `payments` or `users`? auto_increment `user_id` column for `payments` table doesn't make much sense

Comment: @peterm Sorry updated code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

1. It looks like you didn't changed `DELIMITER`.
2. You most likely meant [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) instead of nonexistent `CURTIMESTAMP()`

That being said a syntactically correct version of your trigger might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER users_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users_backlog (user_id, description, datetime) VALUES 
  (NEW.user_id, CONCAT('modified from ', OLD.hourly, ' to ', NEW.hourly), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

or (because you have the only one statement in your trigger you can omit `BEGIN ... END` block and `DELIMITER`) simply

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO users_backlog (user_id, description, datetime) VALUES 
  (NEW.user_id, CONCAT('modified from ', OLD.hourly, ' to ', NEW.hourly), NOW());
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e6bc/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the `DELIMITER` to something different than `;` before running your definition.